# Reference for Cavalieri's principle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request

Does someone know of a reference where I can see Cavalieri's principle (basically the principle that generalized areas can be obtained by multiplying "base times height" -- for constant cross-sectional objects) proven in the *vector language* for objects in $\Bbb R^n$?  To me, it seems like it's at the heart of things like the determinant of a matrix, but I'm not great at proving things and I'd like to see a better mathematician's work.

If no one knows of such a reference, a sketch of the proof would be much appreciated.  I could probably prove it for parallelotopes -- but I'm not even sure how to model general shapes.

Comment: By the way, proof that the volume of a sphere is the volume of a cylinder minus double cone (thus deriving the volume of a sphere): http://www.its.caltech.edu/~mamikon/SpheReduced.html (Also Wikipedia has one for the area of a cycloid)